# Objects NSSet to field elements NSSet

Tags: objective-c

I got `NSSet` with `MyClass`. `MyClass` has field `uid`. I want to get `NSSet` that will contain only uid.Is it possible to do this without iteration though all `MyClass` elements? For example using paths?
The code that works for me:

```
    NSMutableSet *mSet = [NSMutableSet new];
    for (MRCompany *c in sender) {
        [mSet addObject:c.uid];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use kvc to access all the uid as array from the collection of MRCompany and create set with the array like this,

```
NSArray *allUids = [sender valueForKey: @"uid"];
NSSet *mSet = [NSSet setWithArray: allUids];
```

Comment: Thanks! Result is even easier: `allUids` is a `NSSet`